# Nose Test Error

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nosetests

I am using the command

```
nosetests -v --with-coverage --cover-package=task --cover-erase --cover-html-dir=cover --cover-html --with-xunit task
```

to run the test cases
but in the end after running all the testcases I get the nosetests.xml blank and the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/bin/nosetests", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 197, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 61, in run
    test(result)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 176, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 223, in run
    test(orig)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 45, in __call__
    return self.run(*arg, **kwarg)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 138, in run
    result.addError(self, err)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/proxy.py", line 118, in addError
    formatted = plugins.formatError(self.test, err)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 94, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 136, in chain
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/logcapture.py", line 223, in formatError
    test.capturedLogging = records = self.formatLogRecords()
  File "/home/nishant-un/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/logcapture.py", line 231, in formatLogRecords
    return [safe_str(format(r)) for r in self.handler.buffer]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 723, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have tried almost everything that i found in google. Even deleted .coverage file and all .pyc but it still shows the same error.Any Idea..?

Answer (score 0):

This `TypeError` is because of mixing different formats.

Your error is inside `formatLogRecords()`

Instead of:

`msg = msg % self.args`

You should use [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
myMsg = "{} {} {} {} {}".format(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

And even much better approach will be:

```
args = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
myMsg = (' '.join('{}'.format(k) for k in args))
```

Result:

```
>>> 1 2 3 4
```

That way your args can be with a flexible.

Comment: formatLogRecords() is inside the
/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/logcapture.py

Comment: I see but it's still the same error, one of the args cannot be converted because it's with different data types, try to use a debugger and you'll find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to run nose with no log capturing `--nologcapture`. Most likely you have a rogue logging somewhere at the import level, and it chokes nose before tests can run. 
You can usually expose those bugs easily if you just run `python task.py` on your test files - the error will get thrown immediately.

If this still does not solve your problem, try running nose within python using `nose.run()` within your test `__main__` function, and fire it off with `python -m pdb task.py` it will let you debug such errors, even if `--pdb` option in nose does not work.